# git: short status with NUL-terminated names AND relative paths

Tags: git

I want to get `git` output in the format `status -s`:

```
genesis% git status -s .
?? .config/aria2/
?? .config/htop/
?? .config/mc/
?? .config/pacman/
?? .config/remmina/
?? .config/teamviewer/
?? .config/zsh/
```

But I want this list with `\0' terminated filenames to safely deal with files with weird characters in their names.

```
genesis% git status -z . | xargs -0n1 echo
?? misc/.config/aria2/
?? misc/.config/htop/
?? misc/.config/mc/
?? misc/.config/pacman/
?? misc/.config/remmina/
?? misc/.config/teamviewer/
?? misc/.config/zsh/
```

As you can see, the `-z` output gives paths relative to the repository root (the additional `misc`).

How can I get the relative pathnames like in the first example but still have them `NUL`-terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't quite get what you want directly.  However, since `-z` is intended for consumption by *code* rather than humans, you can add a bit of your own code to do what you want, using `git rev-parse --show-cdup`:

```
$ git rev-parse --show-cdup
../
```

This says that there is one top level component "missing" from the current working directory, so after you get your limited-to-current-directory entries via `-z`, you should strip off the first component of each name.  If `--show-cdup` printed `../../` you would need to strip off two, and so on.

Note that `--show-cdup` prints nothing—or more precisely, a blank line—when there are no components to strip off.  Hence, counting the number of `../` (or even just `/`) in `--show-cdup`'s output gives you the correct number of leading path name components to strip.

(If you're providing some argument other than `.` to `git status`, you'll need even more: test whether the argument is a directory, if so `cd` into it and run `git rev-parse --show-cdup`, and if it's a file, get its dirname or `.`, `cd` into that, and run `git rev-parse --show-cdup`.  Do all this from a subprocess to avoid modifying the current working directory of the main process.  This rather convoluted method avoids having to write path name resolvers to handle arbitrary numbers of `./` and `../` components, but you can also go the other route and go straight for full hard paths with `realpath`, assuming POSIX-like environments anyway.)